# Particle filter unexpectedly shows discrete results

Tags: python, montecarlo, resampling, autoregressive-models, particle-filter

I am trying to model an [AR(1) process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model) which generates binary observations with a certain probability.

I have implemented a [particle filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filter) (sequential importance resampling) but its behaviour seems strange.

---

After defining some helper functions:

```
sigmoid2 = lambda x: 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
bern_likelihood = lambda x,y: ( (sigmoid2(x))**y ) * ( (1-sigmoid2(x))**(1-y) )
normal = lambda x, mu, sigma: (1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*pi)))*np.exp((-(1/2)*((x-mu)**2))/(sigma**2))
newVal = lambda nseT:  np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=nseT,size=nParticles)
```

I generate the latent variable:

```
thetaPath = []
x = 0​
AR_noise = .1
​ ​
nTrials = 800
for i in range(nTrials):
    x += np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=AR_noise)
    thetaPath.append(x)

thetaPath = np.array(thetaPath)
​
```

which, via a sigmoid link, generates observed binary data:

```
frac_corr = sigmoid2(thetaPath)
trials = np.random.random(size=nTrials)<frac_corr
```

Then here is my particle filter code:

```
stL = 0
nParticles = 500

#AR_noise = 0.1
dummy = arange(nParticles)

x0 = np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=AR_noise,size=nParticles)   #initialise a set of particles
w0_unNorm = bern_likelihood(x0,trials[0])    #calculate their weights
w0 = w0_unNorm/np.sum(w0_unNorm)    #normalise their weights
xi = cp.deepcopy(x0)
wi = cp.deepcopy(w0)
particle_pths = np.zeros([nParticles,nTrials])
particle_pths[:,0] = cp.deepcopy(x0)
for i in range(1,nTrials):


    #This part does resampling
    if (1/(np.sum(wi**2)))<(nParticles/2):
        #sample with replacement
        resamp =np.random.choice(dummy,size=nParticles,replace=True,p=wi)

        stL += 1   #simple counter for number of times that resampled
        xi = cp.deepcopy(xi[resamp])
        wi = [1/nParticles]*nParticles


    oldxi = xi
    xi += newVal(AR_noise*2)
    wi *= bern_likelihood(xi,trials[i])*normal(xi,oldxi,AR_noise)/normal(xi,oldxi,AR_noise*2)
    wi /= np.sum(wi)

   particle_pths[:,i] = xi
```

Here, my proposal is defined as

```
normal(xi,oldxi,AR_noise*2)
```

While the actual model is

```
normal(xi,oldxi,AR_noise)
```

What I see with both high and low numbers of particles is that the estimates of the underlying state are discrete and jumpy. The estimate for the weighted mean, for both images:
[image]

I don't see this when I'm not resampling:
[image]

---

What could possible be the reason for this behaviour? Is it expected or  there are mistakes in the code?

<sub>(The code supplied should work out of the box after installing relevant modules)</sub>